# Renaming project name shown in JetBrains Toolbox

Tags: jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-toolbox

I've recently made a new Empty Project in IntelliJ IDEA and added a couple Gradle based modules to it. The project and the modules are under `W:\IJ Workspace\ProjectName` directory - the project itself is in `W:\IJ Workspace\ProjectName\ProjectName` folder, and the modules are in `W:\IJ Workspace\ProjectName\ModuleName` folders.

JetBrains Toolbox shows the project and its correct directory (`W:\IJ Workspace\ProjectName\ProjectName`) but the name it displays - is the name of first module I created in the project, not `ProjectName`. Is there any way to change the name Toolbox is displaying for that project? Or is there a way to manually add a project to Toolbox, forcing it to use its actual name?

Comment: Locate a folder with project settings (`.idea` subfolder, usually in PROJECT_ROOT folder). See if you have `.name` file there; if not -- create new one. Open that file in any text editor and write desired project name there -- it's a plain text file with a single line of text. Do that all while IDE is closed. Next time you open that project is should use that name from there. P.S. This works in PhpStorm (where it also has special "Rename Project" action) so should work for IntelliJ IDEA as well.

Comment: Works perfectly :D
Could you add your comment as an answer to this thread, so I can mark it as a solution? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this while IDE is closed (at very least while that project is closed).

1. Locate a folder with project settings (`.idea` subfolder, usually that would be `PROJECT_ROOT/.idea`).
2. See if you have `.name` file there. If not -- create new one.
3. Open that `.name` file in any text editor and write desired project name there -- it's a plain text file with a single line of text (no new lines).
4. Save the file and launch IDE.

Next time you open that project is should use the name from that `.name` file.

P.S. This works in PhpStorm (where IDE also has a special "Rename Project" action) but should work in IntelliJ IDEA (and other IDEA-based IDEs) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Inside project you can change the name used in projects list like Toolbox and windows applications list. Remember to reopen the application.

(1)

- On project root folder
- Shift+F6 or Right click and choose `Refactor | Rename.`
- Then choose `Rename project` in appeared popup.

(2)
Since 2023 You can also use `File | Rename Project` instead.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/renaming-projects.html

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like it only works in PhpStorm - in IntelliJ I don't see any of these two options (the `Rename` option only allows you to rename the module, so it probably does nothing when it comes to renaming the whole project)